# Non-unique input names in Angular scope

Tags: angularjs

I can refer to properties of inputs in an Angular scope like this:

```
<form name>.<input name>.$dirty
```

However this doesn't work if I have multiple inputs with the same name (e.g. in a sub-section of the form generated with `ng-repeat`). In that case `<form name>.<input name>` just holds a reference to the *first* input with that name.

I'm trying to DRY the logic around displaying error messages / classes. To do that I really need to be able to check validity, dirty state and so on. The only other way I can think to do it is to look for `ng-(dirty|invalid)` classes on the input element which feels like a dirty hack.

I also tried using the `$index` variable of `ng-repeat` in the input name (e.g. `<input name="foo[{{$index}}]">`) but then there's only a single property in the FormController with that literal string – not separate ones like `foo[0]`, `foo[1]` etc.

Is there another way to handle this?

Comment: See if this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17422548/1095616) helps.